# Using ROW() with structured referencing to return list of selected records by criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My task is to return a list of items from the records in one table (with structured referencing), from another table (with structured referencing), if the record in the first table "KitList" has a quantity of 1 or greater.

Currently my closest result is using the following formula

```
=INDEX(KitList[Item],SMALL(IF(KitList[Quantity]>0,ROW(KitList[Quantity])),ROW(1:1)))
```

However, this returns incorrect values. Specifically, it returns the row *after* the row containing 1 (or greater), and skips the first row. i.e.

**KitList**

[Item]|[Quantity]

- Item a | 1
- Item b | 0
- Item c | 2
- Item d | 1
- Item e | 0

**Return**

- Item b
- Item d
- Item e

I think this is due to some interaction of the ROW commands counting the headers of the tables, as well as the data in them, therefore reading the range as a whole with the header, and giving an extra row in the return value. Is there a way, in the final ROW command to specify the row I need through structured referencing? Would that fix the problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
{=INDEX(KitList[[#All],[Item]],SMALL(IF(KitList[Quantity]>0,ROW(KitList[Quantity])),ROW(1:1)))}
```

By specifing to the index that I want to include 'all' of the kit list table, the data and the header, not just the header, I've managed to fix the problem. Still seems awkward though.

Comment: Seriously? You're going to accept your own answer as correct when mine fits the criteria in the question exactly AND allows you to move the table if needed??? Geez man.

Comment: Your formula is still effectively the same as guitarthrowers. The code -ROW(KitList[#Headers]) would simply return the value -1. At that point I may as well use -1. Thanks for your feed back though. If it wasn't already obvious I'm slightly new here, though I figured that marking the answer I eventually used (my own), and therefore closing the thread to indicate it didn't require any more attention was what was done. I'll unclose it now.

Comment: My point is that `-ROW(KitList[#Headers])` is objectively superior because the table does not have to be in the first row; if it were in the second row, for example, it would return -2, not -1. It is not "effectively the same as guitarthrowers". Try locating either of your solutions anywhere other than the top row and it will not work. I don't mind you not choosing mine as the correct answer, but your own? Yours is more "effectively the same as guitarthrowers" than my answer. Choose his if you want. Or none. Which you have, so I have no quarrel now.

Comment: Mk, thanks.
If you could 'undown vote' me somehow that would be much appreciated. Being able to comment on others posts at some point in the future would be fantastically helpful to my learning.

Comment: Can't. My vote is locked unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Having discussed this with a few SO users I know in real life, I've been told that I should close this question by marking the code I use. In this case this is definitely my own.

Comment: In addition, for reference, @Rick Teachey is incorrect in his assertion that he can 'move the table'. Not due to a failure in his correction, but as the end of the formula contains ROW 1:1, unless this is changed, a copy/paste of the table which changes it's vertical position will break the results output. Though seeing as this was never part of the original specification, this is inconsequential.

Comment: For reference: @DaveRGP is incorrect. See screenshot. The formula can be copied and pasted exactly as written and the results copied down anywhere. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xvwx8l6jjta5utl/SO-screenshot-24997786.png

Comment: Edited my answer to include screenshot.

Comment: Interpreted your previous statement as movable output table, rather than input. Still not original spec.

Comment: BOTH are movable (as the screenshot demonstrates), so your interpretation is simply erroneous. Movability may not have been originally specified, but a more robust solution should always be preferred if it requires a minimal amount additional complexity (in this case, zero additional complexity). Besides, the original specification was almost as vague as the criteria for selecting the answer now appears to be. I still fail to see how your answer meets it better than mine. But whatever dude.

Answer (score 2):

The `ROW` function will return the row in the spreadsheet, not the row of the structured data. Easy solution `ROW - 1`

Comment: I was aware of that, I was curious if I could specify the structured references differently in order to avoid the issue entierly. -1 seemed clumsy.

Comment: Given the other alternatives you have, `Row - 1` seems much less clumsy than complicated array formulas...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My original answer didn't produce the desired result when copied down.

I think this is what you want:

```
=INDEX(KitList[Item],SMALL(IF(KitList[Quantity]>0,ROW(KitList[Quantity])-ROW(KitList[#Headers])),ROW(1:1)))
```

This will also allow you to move the source `Table` anywhere you want, i.e. the header row doesn't have to be `1:1`, and the results can also be located anywhere as well.

[image]